Advanced Customization of JSON Response Based on User Roles in WordPress REST API
I am enhancing a WordPress plugin to tailor the JSON response for various REST API endpoints, based on user roles. My objective is to dynamically alter the serialization of data so that different user roles can access different sets of data fields. I'm particularly interested in customizing responses for custom post types and need to handle several user roles (e.g., 'administrator', 'editor', 'subscriber', and 'guest') with varying levels of access. Below is my initial attempt using the rest_prepare_<post_type> hook, which lacks granularity and scalability:
function role_based_api_response( $response, $post, $request ) {
    $data = $response->get_data();
    switch (true) {
        case current_user_can('administrator'):
            // No modification for admins
            break;
        case current_user_can('editor'):
            // Editors can't see 'admin_notes'
            unset($data['admin_notes']);
            break;
        case current_user_can('subscriber'):
            // Subscribers only see 'title' and 'summary'
            $data = [
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'summary' => $data['summary']
            ];
            break;
        default:
            // Guests see only 'title'
            $data = ['title' => $data['title']];
    }
    $response->set_data($data);
    return $response;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_my_custom_post', 'role_based_api_response', 10, 3 );


This solution works but isn’t ideal for performance and doesn’t scale well when new roles or conditions are added. I am looking for a more flexible and efficient approach. Specifically:

How can I refactor this to optimize performance, especially considering a large number of API calls?

Is there a way to apply these conditions without extensive use of switch or if statements, possibly through a more dynamic method or design pattern?

Are there any WordPress-specific functions or hooks that provide a more integrated approach to manipulating REST API responses at a deeper serialization level?
I appreciate any insights or examples on how to implement a more robust and scalable solution for role-based data access in WordPress REST API responses.



"isn’t ideal for performance" - can you clarify this? Have you measured the performance impact?

As for #2, I think the next step is some sort of collection or mapping. This could be an array, it could be classes, it could be JSON, etc. This should generally support additional roles. As for conditions, how are you defining the fields? In code or through a GUI like ACF, pods, etc? Ideally the conditions and code, and possibly the roles, would be kept near to each other.

Hey, Chris!
I'm using Redux, it's a plugin similar to ACF for Wordpress. In general I'm trying to find a good approach for frontend manipulations. Sometimes I need to show/hide banners for different user roles. Maybe I need some JSON array to define sections and capabilities, something like
{
"role": "editor",
"sections": [
{ "sectionId": "banner1", "visible": true },
{ "sectionId": "banner2", "visible": false },
{ "sectionId": "banner3", "visible": true }
]
},
And control this array from Wordpress admin panel...

But what's then, should I use something like: if ( apply_role_based_visibility() ) get_template_part();
And still not sure how to control those switch cases and add there cases dynamicaly
